# When DoCmd.OpenForm opens a blank form because no record was found, display a message box that says record is not found

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MainMenu where the user can enter a SchoolID in a search bar (txtSearchBar) and when they click on the SearchBySchoolID button, it opens the form, SchoolForm, based on the SchoolID. Sometimes the user clicks the SearchBySchoolID button without entering anything in the txtSearchBar so when the code below is executed, SchoolForm still opens but it is all blank.

What can I add to my code below so that a message box saying "No SchoolID found" pops up instead of bringing the user to a blank SchoolForm when they type nothing into my search bar?

```
Private Sub SearchBySchoolID_Click()

Dim txtSearchBar As String

On Error GoTo ErrorIDSearch

DoCmd.OpenForm "SchoolForm", , , "SchoolID = " & ("""" &    
Me.txtSearchBar.Value & """"), acFormReadOnly  


ExitErrorIDSearch:

Exit Sub


ErrorSIDSearch:

If Err.Number = 3075 Then

MsgBox "Please enter a valid SchoolID."

    Else

MsgBox "The following error has occured:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & , _
            vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"

         Resume ExitErrorIDSearch

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices

Either put your event handling in the OnOpen event of the form named SchoolForm (and maybe use OpenArgs or an invisible textbox to set some kind of Status on that form so it knows where it was opened from, and why)

or simpler:

Check for existence of the SchoolID in the table before attempting to open SchoolForm

Could use a DLookup or a DCount

e.g.

```
If DCount("SchoolID", "YourTableOrQueryForSchools", "SchoolID=" & """" & Me.txtSearchBar.Value & """") = 0 Then

    MsgBox "Please enter a valid SchoolID.", 64, "Try Again"
    Me.txtSearchBar = ""
    Me.txtSearchBar.Setfocus

Else

    DoCmd.OpenForm "SchoolForm", , , "SchoolID = " & """" &  Me.txtSearchBar.Value & """", acFormReadOnly  

End If
```